# SSRS - How to feed a report parameter "under the rug"?

Tags: c#, reporting-services

I have a parameter in my report that my user cannot know about for security reasons. But this report also has others parameters.
Is there a way to "feed" these reports without the user intervention? I plan to feed default values to the regular parameters and the appropriate value to the "secret one"...

Details:
-Using Report Viewer User control to display the report in a WinForms app
-Using SSRS 2008R2
-Report is not local

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SSRS you can set a parameter to be hidden in the general tab of Report Parameter Properties.

You can then set the parameter using a default value.